# Remove shift/reduce warnings

Tags: bison, yacc

I want to parse a `array name` with `@` followed by any number of words and  a `simple variable` without `@`  again followed by any number of words:

array name example : `@people`

simple variable name : `person`

Sample file which I need to parse :

```
@people name1 name2
person name3 name4
```

I made a rule like:

```
list of record :
line list_of_record
{}
|
line
{};

line
:
AT_SYMBOL string string_list
{}
|
string string_list
{}
;

string_list:
string string_list
{}
|
string
{}
;
//here string is any string
```

But I am getting `shift/reduce`  warnings .Can someone please suggest some kind of approach so that I can remove these warnings.

Comment: that's just too many tags. pick one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell where a `line` ends with that grammar. *Any* `string` could either be one more item in a `string_list`  or the beginning of a new `line`.

So you need to decide how to mark the end of a `line`. If it is a new line character, which seems intuitive, then your lexer will have to pass newline tokens to the grammar.

By the way, it is normally better to use left recursion in a bottom-up grammar. So I'd suggest something like this:

```
 lines: /* empty */
      | lines line NEWLINE
      ;

 line : /* empty, to allow for blank lines */
      | array
      | scalar
      ;

 array: '@' string strings ;

 scalar: string strings ;

 strings: string
        | strings string
        ;
```

The above requires `strings` to be non-empty, so a `line` needs to consist of at least two of them. That might or might not be what you want.

Comment: It probably makes more sense to use `'\n'` instead of `NEWLINE` if you're going to use `'@'` instead of `AT_SYMBOL`